# Newly created Sheet and Script doesn't work anymore

Tags: google-apps-script

I had a sheet and a working .gs script. I use an HTML form to push data into this sheet. It works flawlessly when I deployed it.

Now, I created a new sheet within this same google account where it has the same .gs script copied as well, granted the permission again, then run a new deployment as version 1/2/3/4 or whatever that was. Now on my HTML form, I edited the google sheet script URL to the new script URL, saved it, then cleared my server cache. When I try to submit the HTML form, it doesn't do anything. It catches an error:
[image]

[image]

EDIT: I tried it on my local machine, still my HTML form throws this same error if I copy the sheet and run a new deployment. I even deleted the .gs script of the old sheet. Same issue. Do I need to revoke the permission of the first sheet? Also, I have V8 disabled.

Here's my code:

```js
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)
  
  try {
    
    var sheetName = e.parameter.svdate.split("/").splice(0, 2).map(function(e){return e.replace(/^0/, "")}).join("/");
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'));
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (!sheet) throw new Error("Sheet Name was not found.");
    
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 13).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
    

    var keys = ["id", "confirmation", "questions", "notes"];
    var newRow = headers.map(function (header) { return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : ~keys.indexOf(header.toLowerCase()) ? e.parameter[header] : "" })
    
      var find = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(newRow[0]).matchEntireCell(true).findNext(); 
      if (find) {
        var range = sheet.getRange(find.getRow(), 1, 1, newRow.length);
        var rowValue = range.getValues()[0].map(function(c, i) {return newRow[i] || c});
        range.setValues([rowValue]);
      } else {
        sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);
      }
    
    
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow })+ ")")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
  }
  
  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
    .createTextOutput(e.parameter.callback + "(" + JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e })+ ")")
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT)
  }
  
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Permission:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it. Even though I told earlier that I created a new deployment, when in fact, I only updated this to a new version, not a new deployment.

Here's where I found the issue. Sorry I was being dumb. It's my first week using Google Script. When I posted this thread, the bottom part has the same ID as my previous deployment which shouldn't be. There should be a different ID here for the new script to work. Now I created a new one:

[image]